# CSS borders image border for div element

Tags: html, css

Why does a single image appear in all the four corners?  I only want one image to display

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<html>
    <style>
        div.one{
            border-style: inset;
            border-width:50px;
            border-image-source:url(border1.png);       
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="one">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: then specify the properties for the border-right/left/top/bottom where ever you want to see the effect

Comment: [CSS border-image Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) if you want  one side border you could try e.g. `border-left-image-source: url(border1.png);`

Comment: it dint work too...I want my image border.png...to be displayed as a single image.....but the code i tried is making it appear in all the 4 corners....

Answer (score 2):

No, border-image-source is not supported by any browser.

**Use border-image instead:**

```
div
{
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

In your case:

```
div.one
{
 border-style: inset;
 border-width:50px;
-webkit-border-image:url(border1.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
-o-border-image:url(border1.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
 border-image:url(border1.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/55/

Comment: it fills the entire page ya...See my output should be like the add comment button which you can see on your right..when you try to add comment ....but big in size...forget about the text inside it....imagine it as a box with 4 corner lines

Answer (score 0):

`border-image-source` is a new CSS3 property, which is not yet supported by any of the browsers. Use divs or something else instead to contain images.

Comment: iplanned to add a border-image for a div element so that it would work in IE and firefox...but it is'nt working......

Comment: Forget border-images and everything. Simulate border by pushing an image to the left, right, top, etc.. there are so many solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it work all browsers:**

```
div.one
{
 border-style: inset;
 border-width:50px;
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
 border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

Comment: IT is filling the entire page

Comment: please set class to id for that div. otherwise use only that class name.

Comment: remove border-style: inset,border-width:50px; two line and check,it's work fine.

Comment: try this link http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Comment: when i remove those attributes..the image is disappearing

Comment: user2956454 u got answer.